# What technology is involved in making Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, multiplatform

Programming Languages, Open source libraries and standards adopted to make Firefox works.

Comment: seeing as it's open source, couldn't you look yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a large, long lived project, so it's got far too many to list. Especially when you consider ancillary technologies - for example, the [Elkhound parser](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/) combined with their JavaScript engine creates [Dehydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Dehydra), used to perform static analysis and transform source code, used to bring the old XPCOM stuff up to more recent standards and update dependencies on JavaScript calls.

At the broadest level, the runtime consists of mostly C++ components, configured by XUL interface description language and scripted with JavaScript. IIRC, some of the JS engine code from Adobe is C rather than C++, as are some of the lower level networking libraries. Over recent years, some UI functions have moved from C++ into JS. Then there are the build support and debugging code, which can be Python, perl, make scripts, and so on.

Comment: (given that this answer is now ten years old I've no idea how relevant it still is)

Answer (score 3):

Its all in here :-)
https://developer.mozilla.org/En